# Creating inbox of messages (from Django model)?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to design an inbox for user messages. I have the Message model and I'm trying to display the created messages.

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model): 
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True, 
                    related_name="sender"
                    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True, 
                    related_name="receiver"
                    )
```

profile.html

```
## SIDE BAR (COLUMN 1) 
<div class="tbody">
    {% for message in received %}
    <div class="ui card mcard" onclick="openMessage(--insert--here)">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">{{message.subject}}</div>
                 <div class="text">{{message.text}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    {% endfor %}                
</div>

## COLUMN 2

<div class="ui column"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div id="subject">     </div>
        <div id="firstname">    </div>
        <div id="lastname">     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="text"> </div>
</div>
```

I displayed a list of messages (just subject and sender) in a scrollable side bar. When you click on the card for the specific message, I want all the contents to display in the main (right) column. This is basically how Apple mail works if you know what that looks like.

I'm having trouble getting the right column to display the content because I can't pass the Django Message object to the function (because it's basically running a loop to create cards). Is there a relatively easy solution to this?

TLDR - basically, populate the innerHTML of subject, sender's first name and last name, text when you click on the card for each message.

Comment: Why don't you use javascript for this and access the message object via received[index]?

Comment: @BorkoKovacev The messages aren't stored in an array though. received is a collection of Django objects and I don't think you can index them.

Comment: First of you're not receiving a collection, but rather a QuerySet which you can definitely access via index. Also, instead of thinking, try it - it's extremely rude to ask for help then dismiss it. I'd suggest reading a bit on what [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) is and how [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/) work before asking for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Store the id of the message in the data attribute (see here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Than you can use jquery to get the data, for example `id`

```
$(this).data("id")
```

Than you can call the server to retrieve the message using ajax and populate the right part of page.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by id of the message. Also since this is a Django model, would $(this).data("id") work? I thought you had to filter the model by something instead.

Comment: No need to do an ajaxrequest, when he already has the queryset evaluated and available as a variable inside his template.